# How to make a composite image made from multiple images from user clicks with JS and HTML (Dressup Game)

Tags: html, return-value

I need to be able to use `document.getElementById("myCompositeImage");` to display in DOM a DIV where a dynamic value gets a composite image made from user choices based on this code here on codepen : kristenmay/pen/kkkdBr

When user is OK with the outfit, user should click a button to validate and this action will update the value of the dynamic part in the DIV of the composite image (i can't export the composite image and then use it as an image). This approach or something else, i'm lost :)

Then when I need to display the DIV, user will see the character with the choices of clothes user just made.

I just have no idea how to that (i'm a newbie in JS). If someone want to help, some example code would be very helpful. Thank you for reading.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function ImageSwitcher(choices, i) {
    i = 0;

    this.Next = function() {
      hide_current_image();
      show_next_image();
    }

    var hide_current_image = function() {
      if (choices) {
        choices[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        i += 1;
      }
    }
    var show_next_image = function() {
      if (choices) {
        if (i == (choices.length)) {
          i = 0;
        }
        choices[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  }

  var pants = $(".pant");
  var shirts = $(".shirt");
  var backgrounds = $(".bg");

  var shirt_picker = new ImageSwitcher(shirts);
  document.getElementById("shirt_button").onclick = function() {
    shirt_picker.Next();
  };

  var pants_picker = new ImageSwitcher(pants);
  document.getElementById("pant_button").onclick = function() {
    pants_picker.Next();
  };

  var bg_picker = new ImageSwitcher(backgrounds);
  document.getElementById("bg_button").onclick = function() {
    bg_picker.Next();
  };

});

$("#shirt_button").click(function() {
  $("#shirt-menu").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cc9ad6;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Bunny Dress Up</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dressup.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dressup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default" id="shirt_button" type="button">top</button></li>



    <li><button class="btn btn-default" id="pant_button" type="button">bottom</button></li>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <img id="character" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d5/19/f0/d519f0f021325f16e85a193ec3718130.png" />

  <img id="top1" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/25/43/a9/2543a9ef622c17ca0ccd1fae4441a8ac.png" />

  <img id="top2" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/05/b5/56/05b556aee24a79e17050270c7274de8c.png" />

  <img id="top3" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d7/5c/ba/d75cbab4c752bcd839098e7304fa449b.png" />

  <img id="top4" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/84/07/2f/84072f86cc9c7700367b958b1252527b.png" />

  <img id="top5" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d3/72/cf/d372cf67ffa1073da171f6824ed30140.png" />

  <img id="top6" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/20/72/f6/2072f64b75fb5753a6b038312697fa0d.png" />

  <img id="top7" class="shirt" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/1f/86/b1/1f86b13b426f5ab1483326c97eaa962c.png" />

  <img id="bottom1" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b3/c2/4d/b3c24d75d647564cdaa1d85f854587ba.png" />

  <img id="bottom2" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a5/3a/56/a53a562de60d53e341289584e585f776.png" />

  <img id="bottom3" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2b/26/3b/2b263b07bcdd3d2fafab6ec03402e255.png" />

  <img id="bottom4" style="z-index: 3" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/a6/d7/dda6d7944174edbd743d92360e2ef8f5.png" />

  <img id="bottom5" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/94/c7/15/94c715a60995c215a74a2492a5bea344.png" />

  <img id="bottom6" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/da/1a/16/da1a1609695435ddc106d4f8989f1535.png" />

  <img id="bottom7" class="pant" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c3/78/78/c3787895d353d3b4d8534855ae0b1d83.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to get the contents of a `div` as an image. To be a little more precise it takes a `div` and returns it's contents as a `canvas`.

Here is a complete example.

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="screenshot()">
      Download
    </button>
    <div id="capture">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zC8sER6.jpg" alt="Smiley face" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vt1Bu3m.jpg" alt="Smiley face" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// index.js

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}

function screenshot() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture"), {
    useCORS: true
  }).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    downloadURI(
      canvas
        .toDataURL("image/jpeg")
        .replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream"),
      "yourImage.jpg"
    );
  });
}
```

I did not make use of the images in the code you posted as they have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues. You would not have to worry about it if you own the server(or you use a different source for images) as you could add cors support when required.

If you can by pass the cors issues you could make use of the same code you posted with the addition of html2canvas to satisfy your requirements.